# Losing char when inserting/updating data at SQLite with C#

Tags: c#, sqlite, windows-runtime

I'm trying to execute the following command:

```
db.Query<People>("Update People set FirstName='Sérgio' WHERE PeopleID = 2")
```

Where db is my SQLiteConnection object (provided by SQLite.WinRT). I'm using SQLiteStudio to manage my .db file.
When I update "FirstName" field using SQLiteStudio, it works fine. But when I do it by app, it turns into "S�rgio".

I already checked database PRAGMA, which is UTF-8.

The error seems to be between app and database. Any guesses how to solve it?

Comment: Does this work? `db.Execute("update People set FirstName = ? where PeopleID = ?", "Sérgio", 2);`

Comment: What is the encoding of your source code file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you @chue x. Using your code worked just fine!

> ```
> Does this work? db.Execute("update People set FirstName = ? where PeopleID = ?", "Sérgio", 2);
> ```

Comment: What library are you using? `Query<T>` isn't part of .NET. If this code worked it means that the library sent the SQL statement to the server as ASCII, mangling the name before it was even sent to SQLite. SQLite itself always uses Unicode

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos he appears to be using [sqlite-net](https://github.com/praeclarum/sqlite-net).

Comment: I'm using SQLite.WinRT